# Dropdown routing to different controller/action method seamlessly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

MVC website- On the home page header section, I have a drop down with two options in it. Each option should route to a different Controller/ActionMethod. Since I need this to be in a header section of every page, I put this in the site.master file.

Dropdown code :

```
      <%=Html.DropDownList("OneOrTwo", 
       new List<SelectListItem>
      {
       new SelectListItem{ Text="One", Value = "One" }, 
       new SelectListItem{ Text="Two", Value = "Two" }                       
      }
      , new { @style = "background-color:#f00; border: none;", onchange = 

       "fnNum()" }                    

      )%>
```

In the javascript file, I have this that routes to different controller/action method based on the drop down selection.

```
function fnNum()
{   
    var e = document.getElementById("OneOrTwo");
    var SelValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    if (SelValue == "One")
        window.location.href = "Controller1/Index";  

    else
       window.location.href = "Controller2/Index";      
}
```

There are two issues with this approach :

1. When selection is changed - the newly selected option does not retain. The drop down switches back to original choice even if the web page is showing the new controller/action method view...
2. On subsequent selections of the same choice -  takes me to localhost:/Controller1/Index/Controller1/Index/etc..... there has to be a clean way to do this.

So I want two things :

1. A changed selection should be retained.
2. On subsequent selections, the control needs to be routed properly to controller/index every time and not to controller/index/controller/index...etc..

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you post the rendered HTML of the select box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix problem 1, you have to set the `Selected` property of your `SelectListItems`.  So I would change your code to generate the drop-down to something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("FooOrBar", new List<SelectListItem> {
        new SelectListItem{ Text="One", Value = "Two", Selected = Request.Path == "/Controller1/Index" }, 
        new SelectListItem{ Text="One", Value = "Two", Selected = Request.Path == "/Controller1/Index" }                       
    }, new { @style = "background-color:#f00; border: none;", onchange = "fnNum()" } )
```

The second problem is easier to solve.  It comes from the fact that you're setting the window location to *relative*, not *absolute* URLs.  Just change it to:

```
if (SelValue == "One")
    window.location.href = "/Controller1/Index";  
else
   window.location.href = "/Controller2/Index";
```

Comment: Thank you.. that fixed the issue, but I was using two different site.master files for these two different drop down options. I was wondering how I can use the same site.master page for both options but be able to control what tabs(ul, li items) to display based on the user selection.

Comment: You can use the same technique as I used to determine what `SelectListItem` should be selected.  Just compare against `Request.Path`.